# How can I compute the following situation in R?

Tags: r, estimation, inference

Suppose that an urn contains a number of black and a number of white balls, and suppose that it is known that the ratio of the numbers is $\,3\mathbin{:}1\,$ but that it is not known whether the black or the white balls are more numerous. Find the estimator of the probability of drawing a black ball.

I have done this by the following way :

The probability of drawing a black ball is either 0.25 or 0.75.

If $n$ balls are drawn from the urn, the distribution of $X$, the number of black balls, is given by the *Binomial Distribution*

$f(x;p)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\quad ; x=0,1,2,...,n$

where $p$ is the probability of drawing a black ball. Here $p=0.25$ or $0.75$

We shall draw a sample of three balls, that is, n=3, with replacement and attempt to estimate the unknown parameter $p$ of the distribution.

Let us anticipate the results of the drawing of the sample. The possible outcomes and their probabilities are given below :

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
Outcome:x & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
f(x;\frac{3}{4}) & \frac{1}{64} & \frac{9}{64} & \frac{27}{64} & \frac{27}{64} \\
f(x;\frac{1}{4}) & \frac{27}{64} & \frac{27}{64} & \frac{9}{64} & \frac{1}{64} \\
\end{array}

In the present example if we found x=0 or 1 in a sample of 3, the estimate for $p$ would be preferred over 0.75.

The estimator may be defined as :

$\hat p$ =
  \begin{cases}
  0.25, &\text{for $x=0,1$} \\
  0.75, &\text{for $x=2,3$} \\
  \end{cases}

I want to estimate $p$ for the above situation in R. I tried to do that in the following procedure which seems totally incorrect to me because if several alternative values of $p$ were possible, I can't proceed in the same manner. But I have no better idea:

```
  x=2
  ifelse(x==0 & 1, "hat_p=0.25", "hat_p=0.75")

  x=0
  ifelse(x==0 & 1, "hat_p=0.25", "hat_p=0.75")
```

*How do I compute the above situation in R?*

Comment: Normally this would be migrated to SO but the OP is blocked from asking questions there.

Comment: Why Is The Question Closed?

Comment: Because, as the messages say, it is off topic here: it asks only how to program something in `R`. Please consult our [faq] for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the result of:

```
x <- 1
x==0 & 1
```

-- it doesn't do what you think.

Imagine you have a whole set of observations like the one you describe, all in x, and you want to compute this statistic for all of them:

```
phat <- ifelse((x==0)|(x==1),0.25,0.75)
```

[Besides the method I use above - `(x==0)|(x==1)` (the parentheses are just for clarity there, by the way) - there are other approaches, like `x %in% 0:1`.]

So, for example:

```
x <- c(1,3)
ifelse((x==0)|(x==1),0.25,0.75)

x <- 0:3
phat <- ifelse((x==0)|(x==1),0.25,0.75)
names(phat) <- x
phat
```

But we can back it up a stage and compute the whole table from scratch:

```
binlik <- function(x,p,n) dbinom(x,n,p)
n <- 3
x <- 0:n
p <- c(0.25,0.75)
L.table <- outer(x,p,binlik,n)
ph.ind <- which(apply(L.table,1,max)==L.table,arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]
phat <- p[ph.ind]
names(phat) <- x
phat
```

and we can even write a function to compute $\hat{p}$ for a given $x$ from that computed table (though this one doesn't work on vectors):

```
phatf <- function(x,ph) ph[names(ph)==x]
y <- 3
phatf(y,phat)

y <- 1
phatf(y,phat)
```

Those snippets should give you a few ideas for ways to do things. Check the help on each function, investigate how they work, play with them to see how to use them.